# PHP trim after a certain word

Tags: php

I am trying to replace the words in the array but only after the last empty.png from the post "newOrder" called pixlist. Right now I have it replacing the words with nothing but wish to do the string replace after the last empty.png from $pixlist

```
$replaceThis = array("blank.png", "sold.png", "payed.png");
$pixlist = $_POST["newOrder"];
$pixlist =  str_replace($replaceThis,'', $pixlist);
$trimmed = trim($pixlist);

$filename  =  'pics.txt';
$handle =  fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $trimmed);
fclose($handle);
```

or even better, delete everything after the last word "empty.png" from `$_POST["newOrder"]`

P.S. $pixlist is an array of images

`$pixlist =  trim(substr($pixlist,0,strrpos($pixlist,'empty.png')));`

This works but it deletes the word empty.png, do I change the position to fix it? What do I change?

Comment: I want to execute this code `str_replace($replaceThis,'', $pixlist);` after the last word "empty.png" from `$_POST["newOrder"]`

Comment: what is `$_POST["newOrder"]` and after changed?

Comment: Its an array of picture names. If you can trim everything after the last "empty.png" from the post that can solve everything

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data in $_POST['newOrder']?

Comment: @srtstripes What to do if there is no empty.png string in your array?

Comment: There will always be empty.png to specify the end of the array. But the extra data that comes in after I don't need. I edited the question and found solution I just need help changing position so it wont delete the word empty.png

Comment: @srtstripes so my answer worked? I thought you said newOrder was an array... anyway updated to keep empty.png

Comment: @srtstripes I updated my answer according to your question updates

Comment: @srtstripes then `$_POST["newOrder"]` is not an array otherwise `strrpos` would fail as it does not take arrays which is exactly why I asked you to post a `print_r($_POST["newOrder"]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pixlist =  trim(substr($pixlist,0,strrpos($pixlist,'empty.png')));
```

If you want to keep empty.png:

```
$pixlist =  trim(substr($pixlist,0,strrpos($pixlist,'empty.png')+9));
```

Comment: Yes this is  all I needed, Can't believe I didn't think of this

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do here. What is `'empty.png'`? I only see `'blank.png'`. What is `$_POST["newOrder"]` supposed to be? Is it an array or a string? You're assigning it to a variable called "pixlist" so it sounds like a list, which implies array.

I think we need more details before we can answer your question.

Also, I'm not sure why I can't just comment on the original question. Sorry for using an answer for this, but I didn't see where else to leave a comment.

I still don't know if I fully understand your question, but I assume if given the array below, you want to trim off everything after the last occurance of 'empty.png'. If so, below is how you could do it.

```
$pixlist = array('empty.png', 'image.png', 'empty.png', 'something.png', 'else.png');


// 1. Reverse the array so that we work backwards in from the end, and preserve the original keys.

$pixlist = array_reverse($pixlist, true);


// 2. Search for the first occurance of 'empty.png', since the array was reversed, this will technically be the last occurance.

$key = array_search('empty.png', $pixlist);


// 3. Reverse the array again

$pixlist = array_reverse($pixlist, true);


// 4. Now trim the array using the $key we got from step 2

array_splice($pixlist, $key + 1);


// is now just array('empty.png', 'image.png', 'empty.png');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($pixlist);
```

Comment: Yes its an array, what I really need is to trim everything after the last array called "empty.png"

Answer (score 0):

```
 $pixlist = $_POST["newOrder"];
```

so, i think `$pixlist` is string instead of array.

ok, try to use this code:

```
  $key = 'empty.png';
  $len = strlen($key);
  $pixlist = trim(substr($pixlist,0,strrpos($pixlist, $key) - $len));
```

**update**

```
    $pixlist = 'aaaaaempty.pngabbbbbbbbb';
    $key = 'empty.png';
    $len = strlen($key);
    $pixlist = trim(substr($pixlist, 0, strrpos($pixlist, $key) + $len));
    echo $pixlist;
    // will echo aaaaaempty.png
```

Comment: this worked but deleted the word empty.png,  I just want to delete everything after not the word

Answer (score 0):

You can explode it ... replace in the last element in the array then implode it

```
$data = explode("empty.png", $str);
$last = array_pop($data);
$last = str_replace($replaceThis,"", $last);
array_push($data, $last);
echo implode("empty.png", $data);
```